# Why does this utility method leaves files locked?

Tags: java, file, file-io, locking

I made a simple utility method to read files in Java. Unfortunately, the method appears to leave the file locked after it runs. In others words, even after call the method, and store it in a byte[] I cannot call functions on the file (such as .delete()). I am pretty sure I closed all the channels. Any idea why the file cannot be deleted afterwards? One note is deleting the file works when I call .deleteOnExit(). I know I can use the Files.read() method in the Java 7 API, but I want to know why this method does not work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Converts the file into a byte[]. Also Android compatible. :)
 * @param The File you want to get the byte[] from.
 * @return The byte[]
 * @throws IOException if something goes wrong in reading the file. 
 */
private byte[] mapFileIn(File infile) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileChannel fc = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
        fc = fis.getChannel(); // Get the file's size and then map it into memory
        int sz = (int)fc.size();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, sz);
        byte[] data2 = new byte[bb.remaining()];
        bb.get(data2);
        fc.close();
        fis.close();
        return data2;
    }
    finally{//Ensures resources are closed regardless of whether the action suceeded
        try{
            fis.close();
            fc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Does nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if [this bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7012823) is related to your issue.  It says it was fixed for Java 7, but your reluctance to use Files.readAllBytes suggests to me you might be using something older than 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bb` has not been cleaned up by the GC so there is a still a reference to a file.

The main benefit of memory mapped files is that you can avoid the need to copy the data to/from a byte[] to use it.  If you need a byte[] at the end, I suggest you just read() straight into the byte[].

There is an internal method

```
((DirectBuffer) bb).cleaner().clean();
```

to free the memory mapping.  You have to be *very* sure you won't use this ByteBuffer after calling this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the use of memory mapping. As an aside, your use of memory mapping to simply facilitate reading the entire file into a `byte[]` does not really seem to offer any advantage over a simple read from a `FileInputStream`.

The documentation for [FileChannel.map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) states:

> [T]he buffer and the mapping that it represents will remain valid
>   until the buffer itself is garbage-collected.
>
> A mapping, once established, is not dependent upon the file channel
>   that was used to create it. Closing the channel, in particular, has no
>   effect upon the validity of the mapping.

The documentation for a [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) states something similar:

> A mapped byte buffer and the file mapping that it represents remain
>   valid until the buffer itself is garbage-collected.

This basically means that until the `MappedByteBuffer` is garbage collected, a reference to the file remains. Depending on the OS and the FS, it is conceivable that this mapping could prevent file deletion.

Comment: Ah! So if I add the line `bb = null;` all will be solved? Or is there another way to force garbage collection?

Comment: No. That simply makes it eligible for GC. Currently it becomes eligible once the method completes. When the GC actually occurs is up to the JVM.

Comment: Is there method I can call then? Such as bb.clear()?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. My suggestion would be to avoid memory mapping the file if you want to be able to delete it very quickly thereafter.